# Is it possible to open Firebird database file without installing db server?

Tags: sql, database, firebird

I'd like to inspect an existing Firebird (2.5.1) database without having to
install a server.

Are there any tools out there that allow an inspection of the database file?

If not: Are there any tools I can run on the system where the database server
is actually running to take a look at it?

Comment: "*Are there any tools I can run on the system*". Yes, they are called "SQL clients".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though it's been a while since I posted this question I'd like to give an answer:

I'm now using "Database .NET" from this website:

http://fishcodelib.com/Database.htm

It works reliably and rock solid (especially when used with large databases).

Comment: I needed to install Superserver (as @jonneve says) but after that I was able to open the file with Database .NET

Answer (score 5):

IBExpert's Database Inside allows you to analyse a Firebird database file directly, without a server. Full description here: http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.DatabaseInside

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the embedded server. Full explanations here : http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ufb-cs-embedded.html

Comment: I used the embedded server and actually accessed the database with the program IBQ to inspect and change data.